# Insert into table if second table has conditional value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Table 1 (customers)

```
customer_id   customer_name  salesPerson_id
1             John           1
2             Ed             1
3             Sam            2
```

Table 2 (customerContacts)

```
contact_id   customer_id  phone_number
1            1            687-5309
2            1            555-1234
3            1            742-1111
```

I am trying to let only the sales person add / update a phone number for their specific customer.

So only sales salesPerson_id 1 could update John and Ed and only salesPerson_id 2 could update Sam.

I believe I am looking for something like:

```
INSERT INTO customerContacts (contact_id , customer_id , phone_number) VALUES (1 , 1 , '987-6543')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE phone_number='987-6543'
    IF customers.salesPerson_ID = 1
```

But it doesn't seem like sql supports if statements.

Comment: So is it related to privilege that sales person 1 will login to the database and he should be able to update the phone number of his customers?

Comment: No they'll never actually log in to the database. 
They'll just be logged into a site with the user id stored in a session.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO customerContacts (contact_id , customer_id , phone_number) 
    Select 1 , customer_id , '987-6543' 
    from customers
    where salesPerson_ID = 1 and customer_id=1;
```

This is the query which you should use in the native way but you need to fit this in your application framework

Comment: You have added `()` for the values,do not know if `VALUES` keyword need to be add here

Comment: VALUES keyword is never used in such queries..infact I think () can also be skipped

Comment: Yeah,`()` need to be removed when you use `INSERT INTO SELECT`,https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I had initially tried something similar to this, the problem though is that it doesn't update if there is already a key that exists.

Comment: In such case you can go with before INSERT triggers if they are allowed ..